# creating mysql query using Yii2 Query Builder, strpos: array given

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I'm trying to make query builder to output the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT p1.id, p1.product_id, p1.updated_at
FROM tbl_scrape_data p1
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT max(updated_at) MaxDate, product_id
   FROM tbl_scrape_data
   WHERE product_id IN (1,2,3)       
   GROUP BY product_id
) p2
ON p1.product_id = p2.product_id
AND p1.updated_at = p2.MaxDate
WHERE p1.product_id IN (1,2,3)   
order by p1.updated_at desc
```

Here's what I tried:

```
$scrapeData = (new Query() )
        ->select(['p1.product_id', 'p1.id', 'p1.updated_at'])
        ->from('tbl_scrape_data p1')
        ->innerJoin([
            'p2' => (new Query)
                ->select(['MAX(updated_at) MaxDate', 'product_id' ])
                ->from('tbl_scrape_data')
                ->where([ 'product_id' => [1, 2, 3, 15, 4] ])
                ->groupBy('product_id'),
                //->all(),
            ['p1.product_id' => 'p2.product_id', 'p1.updated_at' => 'p2.MaxDate']
            ])
        ->where([ 'p1.product_id' => [1, 2, 3, 15, 4] ])
        ->orderBy('p1.updated_at DESC')
        ->all();
```

Yii2 throws an error trying to perform this query. Can someone tell me if this is a Yii2 bug or if I'm missing something? Or maybe the way I formatted the query builder is wrong?

I'm using Yii 2.0.1 and the error is

> strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
>
> \vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\QueryBuilder.php at line 715

Comment: Are you sure the error is in that code?I dont see any strpos()

Comment: Yes, please not that I'm using Yii 2.0.1. The function that throws the error is called quoteTableNames in class QueryBuilder. The line looks like this "} elseif (strpos($table, '(') === false) {"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason of the error is in this section of code:

```
->innerJoin([
    'p2' => (new Query)
        ->select(['MAX(updated_at) MaxDate', 'product_id' ])
        ->from('tbl_scrape_data')
        ->where([ 'product_id' => [1, 2, 3, 15, 4] ])
        ->groupBy('product_id'),
        //->all(),
        ['p1.product_id' => 'p2.product_id', 'p1.updated_at' => 'p2.MaxDate']
])
```

Instead of passing two parameters - `table` and `on` separately you actually passing them in one parameter - array.

Also the first parameter (`table`) should be array with one element.

In other words, the placement of square brackets is incorrect.

So here is correct code of the INNER JOIN section:

```
->innerJoin(
    ['p2' => (new Query)
        ->select(['MAX(updated_at) MaxDate', 'product_id' ])
        ->from('tbl_scrape_data')
        ->where([ 'product_id' => [1, 2, 3, 15, 4] ])
        ->groupBy('product_id'),
        //->all(),
    ],
    ['p1.product_id' => 'p2.product_id', 'p1.updated_at' => 'p2.MaxDate']
)
```

Check the official documentation for [innerJoin()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#innerJoin%28%29-detail) method.

Comment: it worked, I had to adjust the ON parameter in order to make it look exactly as my query but the main problem was how I formatted the innerjoin parameters. Thanks @arogachev